# Why won't my generic higher order function accept a method group as argument?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, higher-order-functions, currying

I have the following local method.

```
void Test(int i, int j, int k) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{i} {j} {k}");
}
```

and I have a higher order function as defined below

```
public static class Curry {
    public static Func<T0, T1, Action<T2>> 
        act2f3<T0, T1, T2>(Action<T0, T1, T2> fn) =>
           (T0 t0, T1 t1) => (T2 t2) => fn(t0, t1, t2);

}
```

It splits the original function into two function calls. The first function accepts the first two arguments and the second the final argument. When the second function is called the original function is called with all arguments.

A simple usage is

```
var cfn = Curry.act2f3( Test );
var cfn2 = cfn(0,1);
cfn2(3);
```

Output after cfn2 is called **should be**

```
"0 1 3"
```

however the C# compiler will not allow this.

> The type arguments for method 'Curry.act2f3(Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.

However the following does work

```
 Curry.act2f3( (int i, int j, int k) => Test( i, j, k ) );
```

but doesn't really help as it defeats the purpose of writing this library in the first place. The purpose being a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) process of manipulating function arguments.

Is there a subtle trick I'm missing to get this working?

Comment: Generic type inference doesn't implement deep heuristics, it will frequently stop one layer up or before it would be able to infer the types involved and then spit out that error.

Comment: Frequently I pass method groups to LINQ functions and there is no problem. What is the specific issue here that stops method groups being interchangeable with lambdas?

Comment: Part of the problem here (I think) is that there are two types of inference in play, which delegate to construct around `Test`, and the generic types in the method. If you try this: `Curry.act2f3(new Action<int, int, int>(Test));` then it compiles.

Comment: I guess with local functions being quite new there is room for improvement. I opened a change request at CSharpLang. Maybe something will get done about it. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/798

Answer (score 1):

Thats unfortunate inability of c# compiler to infere the type parameters of passed function `Test`.

The `Curry.act2f3( (int i, int j, int k) => Test( i, j, k ) );` statement works becase you specified the `int` types in declaration `(int i, int j, int k)`.

The `var cfn = Curry.act2f3( Test );` will work if you specify the generic types like this:

`var cfn = Curry.act2f3<int, int, int>( Test );`.